# How do you simplify $\lim_{x\to 1+} e^{\ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x))}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm having an issue trying to figure out parameter to check for what parameter $b$ function is continuous.

$$
\begin{cases}
\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right) &\text{for $x<1$} \\
a &\text{for $x=1$} \\
b\cdot e^{\ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x))} &\text{for $x > 1$}
\end{cases}
$$

In order to solve that, I need to figure out answer for
$$
\frac{-\pi/2}b = \lim_{x\to 1+} e^{\ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x))}
$$

I wanted to use L'Hôpital's rule, but I'm having trouble substituting indeterminate form $e^{0\cdot (-\infty)}$ to $\frac 00$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. I edited your post to improve the formatting using MathJax. Please have a look at the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so you can format your future posts nicely on your own.

Comment: *Mathematica* yields $1$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$ is continuous, this boils down to
$$
\lim_{x\to 1+} \ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x)).
$$
In order to apply L'Hôpital's rule, you can write this as
$$
\frac{\ln(x)}{\ \frac{1}{\ln(\ln(x))}\ }
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\ \frac{1}{\ln(x)}\ }.
$$

---

You can also "simplify" this further by noting that
$$
\ln(x)\cdot\ln(\ln(x)) = \ln\left(\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}\right).
$$
Again, since $\ln$ is continuous you only need to calculate the limit of $\ln(x)^{\ln(x)}$. However, calculating a limit of a function of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ you would usually take the logarithm, so you get back to where you started.

Answer (score 2):

If the limit exists, $$\lim_{x\to 1+} e^{\ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x))}=e^{\lim_{x\to 1+}\ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x))}$$
As you noted, this is a $0\cdot\infty$ type. What you can do it is write it as $$\ln(x)\cdot \ln(\ln(x))=\frac{\ln(x)}{\frac1{\ln(\ln(x))}}$$
This is $0/0$ type of limit. Or you can also get it into $\infty/\infty$ type $$\frac{\ln(\ln(x))}{\frac1{\ln(x)}}$$

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding something, but it seems to me that it would lead me to 
e^(0/0)
which is not the same as 0/0, so i can't use L'Hôpital's rule. Am I wrong?

Comment: Note my first equation. You need to calculate the $0/0$ first

Comment: Right, I missed it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* gives (symbolically) $1$, as supported by the graph:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=\ln x$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 1^+}\ln x \ln\ln x=\lim_{t\to 0^+}t \ln t=0^-$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: You have

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} e^{\ln(x)\cdot {\ln((\ln x))}} = e^{\lim_\limits{x \to 1^+}\ln(x)\cdot {\ln((\ln x))}}$$

So you need to find

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+}\ln (x)\cdot \ln(\ln (x))$$

which is in the form $0(-\infty)$. You can rewrite $\ln(x)\cdot\ln(\ln x)$ to apply L’Hôpital’s Rule, such as by

$$\frac{\ln x}{\frac{1}{\ln(\ln(x))}}$$

Comment: I think it should be $(\ln x)^{\ln x}$

Comment: Yes, corrected.

Comment: Did you forget to get rid of the $\ln$ when cancelling it with the exponential?

Comment: Oops, I’ve corrected it.